# MS Access - Command button wont function at all

Tags: ms-access

I have tried to Google and review previous Stackoverflow posts but I cannot seem to find a solution and this seems like such a simple fix.

I put a Command button in my Form because i wanted to test exporting information within the form to an Excel spreadsheet.

```vb
Private Sub cmdExportFilename_Click()
    Dim sFilename As String

    sFilename = "C:\Users\Redacted\Desktop\exportResults.xlsx"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "OpenComplaintsQuery", acFormatXLSX, sFilename, AutoStart:=True
End Sub
```

I made sure the OnClick event was set to [Event Procedure] but when i go into form view and click nothing happens not even an error so i feel like i am still missing something that is telling that button to run that code. i checked my Trust Center settings and changed it to enable code but still nothing.

Any advice is helpful!

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint on the line `sFilename = ...` to if the code is executed? See: [Debugging VBA Code](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code).

Comment: "I have tried to Google ....", It seems you did not find: [Use a command button to start an action or a series of actions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-command-button-to-start-an-action-or-a-series-of-actions-c7bf2827-2f3e-42b8-83d6-6c4f0de78990)

Comment: The event handlers are attached by name. If you have a sub `cmdExportFilename_Click` the button must have the name `cmdExportFilename`. You can also click on the `...` button to the right of On Click [Event Procedure] to create or jump to an existing event handler Sub.

Comment: That did the trick, I am surprised at myself that I missed that. I changed the name of the button to the Sub name and it performed it's task. I am ready to fine tune the code to get the ideal results. Thank you for your help.